# html sub list automatically adding padding

Tags: html, css, padding

I m having a list which has a sub list, which I am populating with two DIVs, both FLOAT(ed) to the left.

The structure is like -

```
<ol> <li>
    <ol>
    <li>
        <div>first div</div>
        <div>second div</div>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ol>
</li>
</ol>
```

Now, the first floated left is a image which is doing fine, but the other left(with text shifted to the right) automatically **adds a auto-padding of 7px at the top** for which I have to do a padding-top on the first image div.

**How do i remove the auto-padding in the second div?**

The example [here](https://jsbin.com/royemopiyi/edit?html,css,output)

I have marked out the problem in red in this image -
[image]

Comment: Try removing the `padding-top` you added for the image and add a negative `margin-top: -5px;` to `.com_text`, adjust the margin to match your needs

Comment: You nailed it @phobia82 . Where did you get the negative padding thing?

Comment: Negative padding is not allowed, but negative margin does: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Comment: I will add it as an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative [margins](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp), this will allow you to move the elements on any direction. In your case, you can add a negative `margin-top` to the second div.

```
.com_text {
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Comment: although where the positive margin is coming from still remains a mystery, good to go for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can write css for the second div by using this:

```
li:nth-child(2) {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: that is already there in the question - ol.timeline ol li { padding:0px;}

Comment: But it's there for all the li element. the above code will target only 2nd element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe correcting the CSS will get you the result:

```
.comm_img{
    padding-top:5px;
}

.comm_text{
    margin-top:0px;
}
```